# AppBar in Material ui is not reflecting in chrome browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui, node-modules

I am new to react.I am trying to display appbar using material ui in react project. but i can't see the output of it. I have the latest version of the material ui and react.

but the same code is running on codesand box ide on web.
I don't know why it is happening
this is my file structure:
[file structure][1]

These are the versions of the node modules:
[versions of my node modules][2]

The App.js file:
[App.js][3]

this is expected:
[Expected output screen][4]

but got this:
[obtained output screen][5]

this is my index.js file:
[index.js][6]

```
    import React from 'react';

import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

import VideoPlayer  from './components/VideoPlayer';
import Notifications from "./components/Notifications";
import Options from "./components/Options";


const App=()=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <AppBar position="static" color="inherit">
                <Typography variant="h2" align="center">Video Chat</Typography>
                
                </AppBar>
                <VideoPlayer/>
                <Options>
                    <Notifications/>
                </Options>

        </div>);
}
export default App;
```

Thanks in advance for who has replied for my post. thank you for getting me out of this error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms4fI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxLnC.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VfvN.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFDg0.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMK0E.jpg
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GWKQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an import issue. Material UI is now  [MUI](https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/) If you have the latest version of Material you might need to change the import.

```
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
// or
import { AppBar } from '@mui/material';
```